# How do I prevent rehashing of an std::unordered_map while removing elements?

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, hashtable, unordered-map

I have an std::unordered_map that I will be removing elements from via iteration.

```
auto itr = myMap.begin();
while (itr != myMap.end()) {
    if (/* removal condition */) {
        itr = myMap.erase(itr);
    } else {
        ++itr;
    }
}
```

I would like to prevent the map for performing any expensive operations until I'm done removing all of the elements that I need to remove.  Do I have a valid concern?  Am I misunderstanding how the internal storage works?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The unordered containers are forbidden from rehashing during an `erase`:

[unord.req]/p14:

> The `erase` members shall invalidate only iterators and references to
>   the erased elements, and preserve the relative order of the elements
>   that are not erased.

[unord.req]/p9:

> Rehashing invalidates iterators, changes ordering between elements, and ...

Your code is fine as is.

Comment: I know we're looking at this question 4 years later, but I'm really glad to see this answer enter the mix. Looking at the documentation again, it's pretty clear that the worst-cast complexity comes not from potential rehashing, but instead from hash collisions. I think this is officially the correct answer.

Comment: so table can only grow.?

Comment: The number of buckets in an unordered container will never shrink under `erase`.  The number is allowed to shrink under `rehash`, and all implementations will do so.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, `std::unordered_map` is allowed to rehash on `erase(itr)`:

> C++11 Table 103 -- Unordered associative container requirements
>
> `a.erase(q)`
>
> Erases the element pointed to
>   by `q`. Return value is the
>   iterator immediately following `q`
>   prior to the erasure.
>
> Average case
>   `O(1)`, **worst
>   case
>   `O(a.size())`**

It would therefore seem that you do have a valid concern. As to addressing it, I can suggest several avenues:

1. Make sure it's an actual problem rather than a hypothetical one. Profile the application, look at the source code for your C++ library, etc.
2. If it is an actual problem, consider using a different container or a different algorithm.
3. Consider simply marking the elements for deletion through a boolean flag associated with each element, and sweeping the deleted elements from time to time, thereby amortizing the costs.
4. Consider experimenting with the load factor, as suggested by @amit in the comments. Even though the container would still be allowed to take `O(a.size())` time to erase elements, a different load factor might have an effect on the real-world performance of your application.

Comment: Though informative and related - it does not answer the question: `How do I prevent rehashing of an std::unordered_map while removing elements?`

Comment: @amit: If you read between the lines, it does (the answer to that exact question is that you can't :))

Comment: Not sure you can't, you could set the max_load_factor to an imaginary high value, and resetting it back to a normal size later on. I could not find anything that confirms this in the docs (thus not posting an answer) - but I suspect it will enable you to control the rehashes and have at most 2.

Comment: I think it's worth it to point out that the size of the table would be reduced in a relatively predictable manner.  That's to say, basically, that given the total percentage reduction of the table, the number of rehashes necessary to reduce it to that size (assuming a single element erased per remove) would be calculable.

Comment: @NPE I can accept that: Figure out if it's a problem, if so, use a different container.

Comment: @amit: Well, the worst case is stated as `O(a.size())`. It is not predicated on anything else, including load factors.

Comment: @NPE: the worst case is based on really bad hash values, not on rehashing. All unordered_* operations are subject to the possibility that all the objects in the container at the moment happen to have the same hash value. I'm almost certain that .erase is currently forbidden from rehashing.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  I've added a correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure it will work, I do not find a confirmation for it in the documentation - but if the unordered_map is rehashing according to the classic hash table data structure, you could **[set the max_load_factor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/max_load_factor/)** to a very high value and reset it back to normal when you are done (which will trigger a rehash) (or to predicted value if you can predict how many elements will be removed).

In terms of classic hash table, it should work since rehash when decreasing the table occures when the size is lower then `1/max_load_factor`.

(not sure it is the case in C++, but I assume it worthes the try, since it is really easy to implement).